# Issue presenting empty tableview text and image

Tags: swift, tableview

Essentially I have a tableview that must display an image text when it is not presenting any rows.

I have the following structure decoding the JSON:

```
var sections = [JSONSection]()


struct JSONSection {
    let date : String
    var items : [JSONStructure]
}

struct JSONStructure: Decodable {

    let person: String
    let processtime: String


    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case person, processtime
    }

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let section = sections[section].items


    if section.count == 0 { tableView.setEmptyView(title: "Text", message: "Message")
    } else {
        tableView.restore()
    }

    return section.count

}
```

I get no error but instead of the custom message I just get a blank tableview (White background)

This is most likely caused by how I am writing the conditional, am I defining sectionn.count wrong?

Comment: Are you following this? : https://medium.com/@mtssonmez/handle-empty-tableview-in-swift-4-ios-11-23635d108409

Comment: Right, but the custom message is not being displayed, in fact I tried putting `print("Empty tableview")` and it did not print that. Which means section.count is wrong

Comment: I think you need to print `section` first. Check what is the value of section.

Comment: Nothing is printing for section either.

Comment: So, what is `section.count`?

Answer (score 0):

Set your dataSource and delegate in viewDidLoad:

```
self.tableView.delegate = self
self.tableView.dataSource = self
```